# Compare datatype of all the columns of tables with one configuration table in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I  have one table CONFIG_PRAM which contains columns like  `colname` , `datatype` and many more details of existing tables.

Example

```
CREATE TABLE CONFIG_PRAM 
(   colname varchar(40),  
   datatype varchar(40)  
 );
```

I have to compare those columns and datatype present in CONFIG_PRAM table with the existing table`s  columns.

Example: I have one existing table **test1** table in database

```
create table test1 ( employee_id   NUMBER(6),
                     sal    NUMBER(6,8));
```

And if I found any mismatch I need to update CONFIG_PRAM table with correct data type.

FOR above one in CONFIG_PRAM table we have  `sal number`
but actually it is `number(6,8)` in table so I have to update CONFIG_PRAM table  with exact datatype.

I have tried like this:

```
select distinct colname , datatype 
from CONFIG_PRAM , all_tab_columns
where upper(column_name)=upper(colname )
and data_type=datatype 
and table_name in ('TEST1')
```

But Suppose Table A has `Number(6,8)`
and CONFIG_PRAM table contain only `Number` 
then it is not giving correct results.
Issue is this query is not comparing decimal values exactly. Can you please provide a solution for this in sql/PLSQL?

Answer (score 1):

This query joins your table to ALL_TAB_COLUMNS on the basis of COLUMN_NAME. This means it only works properly when CONFIG_PRAM has entries for just the one table. Perhaps it needs a column for TABLE_NAME as well?

```
select cp.colname 
       , cp.datatype as config_datatype
       , atc.data_type as actual_datatype
       , atc.data_length as actual_length
       , atc.data_precision as actual_precision
       , atc.data_scale as actual_scale
from CONFIG_PRAM cp
     join all_tab_columns atc
     on atc.column_name = cp.colname
where atc.owner = user 
and atc.table_name in ('TEST1')
and upper(cp.datatype) != case 
       when atc.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' 
            then atc.data_type||'('||atc.data_length||')'
       when atc.data_type = 'NUMBER' 
            and instr(cp.datatype, ',') = 0
            and atc.data_scale = 0 
            then atc.data_type||'('||atc.data_precision||')'
       when atc.data_type = 'NUMBER' 
            then atc.data_type||'('||atc.data_precision||','||atc.data_scale||')'
       else atc.data_type
       end 
;
```

The WHERE clause compares your `datatype` column with an assembled datatype string. Obviously there are more potential datatypes than this query handles. You will need to extend it as necessary. Also, variations in the formatting of the datatype string will produce false positives. So you should have a proper think about the structure of your CONFIG_PRAM table: the looser the rules you apply on insert or update the more work you have to do when it comes to selecting it for use.

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a682f/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I will check with some more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

[`ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.html) contains many more columns than just `data_type`. You will also need to compare at the very least `data_length`, `data_precision` and `data_scale`.

Your join is also missing `table_name` and `owner`, and it is better to use ANSI join syntax.

Comment: I have tried this -- 
                       select * from config where cname not in (
                       select  distinct cname from config c , all_tab_columns
                       where upper(column_name)=upper(cname)
                     and data_type=dtname  
                     -- and table_name in ('TEST1') 
                      and nvl(Substr(c.dtname,8,1),0)=NVL(DATA_PRECISION,0)
                      and nvl(Substr(c.dtname,10,1),0)=nvl(DATA_SCALE,0));                 But I dont want to hard code this (Substr(c.dtname,10,1),0). any alternative?

Comment: Please add this to your question as comments like this are not readable. Also you need to use table aliases like `from all_tab_columns tc`.